# Eclipse Luna - dark theme : set the CDT outliner font color

Tags: eclipse, themes, osx-yosemite

How could I change the CDT outliner font?

I use the builtin dark theme but the outliner font is black on some variables (define and include). Obviously, I have some issues to read the text.

How can I change that ?

Details:

- Eclipse Luna
- Dark theme
- OSX yosemite

Answer (score 0):

Did you check Windows > Preferences > Java (or whichever) > Editor > Syntax Coloring - choose the element and change the coloring.

Comment: Yes I tried that. It is c++ by the way but same thing. The problem only occurs in the outliner, where you have the list of all the functions. Nowhere else.